# ASP Net MVC - Send different model on POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

is it possible to send an object from a strongly typed view to the Controller via Http-POST that does not equal the type of the original model.

For example:

I have a ViewModel like this:

```
public class PersonsViewModel
{
    List<PersonViewModel> persons { get; set; }

    PersonsViewModel() { }
}

public class PersonViewModel
{
    //some properties

    Person() { }
}
```

Now i have this View:

```
@model PersonsViewModel

<div>
  @for(int i = 0; i > Model.persons.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(Model.persons[i])
}
</div>
```

The editor could look like this:

```
@model PersonViewModel

<div>
     @using (Html.Beginform("Postaction","Controller", FormMethod.Post)){
     <div>
       <!-- properties and textboxes here + submit button -->
     </div>
}
<div>
```

The controller action

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Postaction(PersonViewModel model)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

This doesn't work because it seems the Controller is expecting a PersonsViewModel object. My workaround so far is to make a "big" Form that contains all PersonViewModel and send the complete PersonsViewModel to the controller.

Is it somehow possible to pass only one PersonViewModel to the Controller although the view is strongly typed?

Kind regards,
Martin

Comment: To the first question, the short answer is NO (by default in MVC). The ModelBinder compares the name of the fields you passed to make a match with the type you declared in your action. You should take a look to custom model binder : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder

Comment: Generally you would send the ID of the PersonViewModel to the Controller where it would then query a data source to retrieve the data object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be done:

When used with collections `Html.EditorFor` is smart enough to generate input names that contain index so `ModelBinder` could successfully create a model as a collection of objects. In your case since you want to have a separate form per `PersonViewModel` object, you could create a partial view as a template for editing `PersonViewModel` and use `Html.RenderPartial` helper:

Assuming you have `_PersonViewModel.cshtml` partial view

```
@for(int i = 0; i > Model.persons.Count; i++)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_PersonViewModel", Model.persons[i]);
}
```

in the _PersonViewModel.cshtml you can not use neither one of editor helpers such as `Html.EditorFor`,  `Html.TextboxFor` because they are going to generate identical ids for the same properties so you will have to manually create html inputs:

```
@model PersonViewModel

<div>
     @using (Html.Beginform("Postaction","Controller", FormMethod.Post)){
     <div>
       @*Nottice the usage of Html.NameFor(m=>m.FirstName) for generating a name property value *@
       <input type="text" name="@Html.NameFor(m=>m.FirstName)" value="@Model.FirstName"> 
     </div>
}
<div>
```

This way you can post a single `PersonViewModel` object to the controller action

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for